# ffmpeg: Unrecognized option 'frames:v' Failed to set value '1' for option 'frames:v'

Tags: ffmpeg, debian

I am on debian
I installed ffmpeg with

```
apt-get update
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

When I run:

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf  "thumbnail,scale=640:360" -frames:v 1 thumb.png
```

I got this error

```
ffmpeg: Unrecognized option 'frames:v' Failed to set value '1' for option 'frames:v'
```

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: You need to include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
> ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i DSCN5055.MOV -vf  "thumbnail,scale=640:360" -frames:v 1 thumb.png
> file thumb.png 
thumb.png: PNG image data, 640 x 360, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

This is ffmpeg 2.2.4
Does input.mp4 exist, and does it contain playable video? Could you play this file with ffplay?